# Reflection transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations

> Let $F:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ be defined as $F(x,y)=(\cfrac{3x+4y}{5}, \cfrac{4x-3y}{5})$. Then $F$ is a reflection.

My attempt: Let $F$ be defined in vector form, $F\pmatrix{x \\ y}=\pmatrix{\cfrac{3x+4y}{5} \\ \cfrac{4x-3y}{5}}=x\pmatrix{3/5 \\ 4/5}+y\pmatrix{4/5 \\ -3/5}$, then $$F\pmatrix{x \\ y}=\pmatrix{3/5 & 4/5 \\ 4/5 & -3/5}\pmatrix{x \\ y}$$

If it is a reflection, then a line of reflection $L$  must exist. Then $L$ must be orthogonal to every segment $PF(P)$. Let $L=\pmatrix{l_1 \\ l_2}$, then for every $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$, the dot product of $\vec{L}$ and the segment $\pmatrix{\cfrac{2x-4y}{5} \\ \cfrac{-4x+8y}{5}}$ should be zero. To verify, \begin{align*} \cfrac{2x-4y}{5}l_1+\cfrac{8y-4x}{5}l_2&=0 \\ 2xl_1-4xl_2-4yl_1+8yl_2&=0 \\ (2x-4y)(l_1-2l_2)&=0\end{align*} thus the line of reflection exists for which $x=2y$. Since $L$ exists, then $F$ must be a reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did proves that *if* $F$ is a reflection, *then* the line of reflection is the line $l$ defined by $x=2y$. It remains to be proved that $F$ is indeed the reflection through $l$. If $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$, then the midpoint between $(x,y)$ and $F(x,y)$ is$$\left(\frac{2}{5} (2 x+y),\frac{1}{5} (2 x+y)\right),\tag1$$which belongs indeed to the line $l$. And the distance from $(x,y)$ to $(1)$ is equal to the distance from $F(x,y)$ to $(1)$. Since $l$ is orthogonal to the segment from $(x,y)$ to $F(x,y)$, $F$ is indeed the reflection through $l$.

Comment: what if I proved l is unique, then would that be sufficient to claim F is a reflection about l?

Comment: You are saying that $l$ is the unique line with respect to which property?

Comment: I’m thinking the parallel postulate. No other line that contains the midpoint and be perpendicular to the segment PF(P) can exist, since then it would be parallel to L and contain midpoint M. but that is impossible, since two lines are either distinct or parallel. does that reasoning work?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, but I don't see how is it that you deduce from it that $F$ has to be a reflection about the line $x=2y$. Anyway, if you are not interested in my answer, I will delete it.

Comment: Oh no, I like your answer. I just wanted to make sure if my own intuition was correct.